# Undefined reference to my own library

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, undefined-reference, unix-ar

I've created my lib.a file with several

```
gcc -c file.c -o file.o
```

then

```
ar sr lib/libtest.a file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

confirmed with

```
ar -t lib/libtest.a
file1.o
file2.o
file3.o
```

but when I try to compile test aplication

```
gcc lib/libtest.a test.c -o test
```

I got undefined reference in function `main`: 
to used function from file1.o, file2.o, file3.o

Comment: See [GCC Link Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order matters with libraries - try:

```
gcc test.c -o test lib/libtest.a
```

Basically, the linker reads the library when it comes across it on the list of input files (this may not be exactly how things work, but I think it works well as a rule of thumb) and will resolve any still-undefined references remaining. When it moves on to the next input, it won't look to that library again for any new unresolved references it picks up along the way.

(Note: there are certain linker options that can change this behavior, but they seem to be rarely used and probably have their own set of drawbacks so I don't discuss them here.  this kind of problem is usually resolved by reordering the linker's input file list).

Comment: +1 on that. Note that this is only really an issue with static libraries, as ld will select which of the object files from the archive to link with. There is `--whole-archive` which is perhaps one of those exotic options you've mentioned, but again uncommon and not ideal (because you might be linking against a potentially large blob). It is useful however if you are including this in library code itself (i.e. generating a .so from multiple .a's).