# Undefined reference to _gzopen etc

Tags: windows-7, g++, cygwin, mingw

Hi I have a program in c built on a non Windows machine(ubuntu machine I think but could be mac os as well).

I did a quick look around and tried cygwin (installed cygwin, used the terminal to goto the directory containing the c program and called make.)

This yields:

```
$ make
g++ -lz -Wextra -O3 -o bin/lda src/lda_main.o src/data.o src/lda.o c/lda_init.o
   src/lda_io.o src/lda_sampler.o src/opts.o

src/data.o:data.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `_gzopen'
src/data.o:data.cpp:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `_gzgets'
src/data.o:data.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `_gzgets'
src/data.o:data.cpp:(.text+0x1f0): undefined reference to `_gzgets'
src/data.o:data.cpp:(.text+0x257): undefined reference to `_gzclose'
src/data.o:data.cpp:(.text+0x3cb): undefined reference to `_gzopen'
src/data.o:data.cpp:(.text+0x498): undefined reference to `_gzgets'
src/data.o:data.cpp:(.text+0x4b4): undefined reference to `_gzclose'

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: src/data.o:
   bad reloc address 0x1c in section `.eh_frame'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:16: recipe for target `lda' failed
make: *** [lda] Error 1
```

I do have gcc g++ installed as well as zlib.

I then tried mingw32 using mingw32-make in the right directory.
returns an error faster than eye can see:
`ld.exe: cannot find -lz`

Any suggestions? Please keep in mind that I am an economist by training and we know how useful that is :-). Simple will go far with me.

Comment: I have made some changes that I think will help but feel free to revert. Also, [this old post](http://lists.osuosl.org/pipermail/darcs-users/2004-September/003222.html) seems relevant, you might want to try the same example

Comment: Actually I find Mr. Burr's response comprehensive and clear. I agree with your title edit - more likely someone will look for that (I certainly did!). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the makefile so that `-lz` comes after the list of object files.

With the command line:

```
g++ -lz -Wextra -O3 -o bin/lda src/lda_main.o src/data.o src/lda.o src/lda_init.o
   src/lda_io.o src/lda_sampler.o src/opts.o
```

The library will not be searched for external references that the various object files need. If you arrange it so the command looks like:

```
g++ -Wextra -O3 -o bin/lda src/lda_main.o src/data.o src/lda.o src/lda_init.o
   src/lda_io.o src/lda_sampler.o src/opts.o -lz
```

Then `libz` will be searched for any external references that the object files need.

Comment: If it is at the end then the linker will find it even though it does not find it when it is at the beginning?

Comment: @MiserableVariable: yes - the library gets searched once when the linker processes it in command line order.  Anything that's not needed from the library at the moment isn't pulled in. The library is not searched again to resolve subsequent needs. This behavior is specific to the GNU `ld` linker, and may or may not be the same for other linkers (for example, MSVC's linker behaves differently). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10421543/12711 and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html for details.

Comment: Gracias Senor Burr. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Ok no cigar as yet. I find an executable in the bin folder. however upon cliking this i get cygwin1.dll not installed. does this mean i cannot now use the exe file as I would any exe file on windows?

Comment: And cygwin1.dll is in my PATH.

Comment: When you launch an executable using the mouse in Explorer, the PATH used is Explorer's - which might not match the PATH in a command window you might have used to build the program. Try running the program from the environment used to build it. To get it to run from Explorer, you might need to set the PATH correctly in your Computer Properties "Advanced systems settings" dialog.  It may also require a logoff/logon or maybe even a restart of the machine.

Comment: OK - retyped in the address in the PATH and this time it did work! my executable is running nicely. Must have been an extra space or something that i missed the last time around. Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: Is this a predefined behavior? All systems will behave like this?